# Why can't I install Modern Warfare 3?

Tags: installation, autoplay

When I insert the Modern Warfare 3 DVD, Windows loads for a while and then this window opens:

[image]

Why is there no option to install the game?

If I double click the DVD from My Computer, it just lets me browse the DVD.

[image]

Am I missing anything? My DVD reader is a Samsung SH-S223C 22X DL Black.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the second picture, it looks like you are using disk 2!

Take a look back in the pack and find Disk 1, start the setup from that.

Comment: What? They still ship manuals for software!?